# ROBLOX Studio: How do I assign a player to a team every time they reset/respawn/refresh their character?

Tags: lua, roblox

ROBLOX Studio: How do I assign a player to a team every time they reset/respawn/refresh their character?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a listener for the [Player.CharacterAdded event](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Player/CharacterAdded) which is fired every time a characters spawns or respawns.

In that listener assign the team to the [player's Team property](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player#team)